# CakePHP 3 custom form

Tags: cakephp-3.7

I am using CakePHP3 and Angular to provide some front-end validation on form inputs. This is working nicely but I'm looking to minimise my front-end mark-up - as follows:

```
$this->Form->control('Name', [
     'placeholder' => 'Test', 
     'ng-model' => 'listing.test',
     'templateVars' => [
          'has_errors' => 'ng-class="{\'has-error\': addListing.$submitted && addListing.name.$invalid}"',
          'error' => '<div class="error-message" ng-show="addListing.$submitted && addListing.name.$invalid">Please specify your name</div>',
     ]  
]);
```

In my app_form.php I have the following:

```
'input' => '<input class="form-control mb15" type="{{type}}" name="{{name}}"{{attrs}} />{{error}}',
```

I don't want to have to repeat '<div class="error-message"...' for each and every input, it would be better to just pass in the the 'ng-show'.

My thoughts were to do something like tihs:

```
'templateVars' => [
     'has_errors' => 'ng-class="{\'has-error\': addListing.$submitted && addListing.name.$invalid}"',
     'show' => 'addListing.$submitted && addListing.name.$invalid',
     'message' => 'Please input your name' 
]

'customError' => '<div class="error-message" ng-show"{{show}}>{{error-message}}</div>',
'input' => '<input class="form-control mb15" type="{{type}}" name="{{name}}"{{attrs}} />{{customError}}',
```

However I think this customisation beyond what is possible since I would be creating my own template key. Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe I just don't get the point, but why don't you directly put the error `div` in the `input` template? Or how about modifying CakePHP's default `error` template?

Comment: @ndm the first option might fly, the second I don't think will work because Cake's validation is server-side but in my case I am firing validation client-side, therefore I don't think the template will appear when  need it to